# How to Identify source node of received packet of XBee in arduino?

Tags: arduino, xbee

I am sending packets from two Routers to a Coordinator in my XBee network. I want to know which Router sent this received packet at Coordinator. I am using API mode for both Routers and Coordinator.

I am not sending any identity in packet data, it's just a random data. Is there any way to identify source of packet from its frame details.

Comment: What do the frames look like that you're receiving?  Frame type 0x10 and 0x11 include addressing, and are received as 0x90 and 0x91.  Are you using a code library, or manually sending bytes over the serial port?

Comment: I am using `<Xbee.h>` and `<SoftwareSerial.h>` libraries in arduino and sending frame by `ZBTxRequest(addr64, data, sizeof(data));`

Comment: And where did you get the `Xbee.h` and related code?  Read that documentation and you should be able to identify APIs/function calls to access the sender's address of a frame.